# Flutter Project Creation Error Bash (Operation not Permitted) on Mac Big Sur

Tags: flutter, android-studio, macos-big-sur

i Can't successfully create a flutter project on my newly downloaded Android Studio. All i get is an error  on the screenshot below.[Project Creation Error, Bash: /Users/username/.. (Operation not Permitted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n9u8.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

After few days, of trying different solutions, i finally decided to try these and it worked:

1. Go to your Mac System Preferences
2. Navigate to Security and Privacy
3. Click Privacy Tab
4. click Full Disk Access
5. click the + below
6. ADD ANDROID STUDIO application
7. restart android studio and that's it.

Hope this helps someone :)[Add Android Studio to Full Disk Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyOra.png)